# I'm adding a React people picker to an spfx webpart app and having trouble setting it dynamically

Tags: spfx-webparts, react

I've build an app in a webpart with a React people picker contained in its own div. It's the only React component. I need to dynamically clear and add users to the people picker from the webpart scope. I'm new to React and am wondering what's the best approach without resorting to global variables. Should I unmount the component and re-create it, or create a wrapper to dynamically set the props. or ...?

Comment: Please share your code to understand your exact problem